# DD-WRT QoS not working on LAN/WLAN interface

Tags: lan, dd-wrt, bandwidth, wan, qos

I have a TP-Link WR941ND with DD-WRT firmware. Another ISP provided router dials the PPPoE connection for internet. The DD-WRT router was connected to the ISP router once through LAN in DHCP forwarder mode and another time in Wireless Client Bridge mode as a Range Extender.

In both scenarios, QoS set to Lan/Wlan ports did not work and any of the connected devices were able to use as much bandwidth as needed. However, when I connected the DD-WRT router through its WAN port and use it as a main router that dials the connection, the QoS works fine, when set to WAN port.

Am I doing something wrong or is it only supposed to work through WAN port?

[image]
[image]

Comment: what kind of packet scheduler do you use?

Comment: @MTG I’ve tried both of HTB and HFSC but same results. Only works through the WAN port.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of your current qos setup?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart screenshots have been attached.

Comment: possible duplicate of this question. https://superuser.com/questions/1292147/configure-dd-wrt-to-limit-bandwidth-on-devices/1301785#1301785

Comment: @Tim_Stewart no it’s not. Already went through that. It’s how to set up the configuration when it works, not when it doesn’t.

Comment: the configuration you posted would have never worked in either case... you dont have it configured correctly. read that post carefully. each method works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't set the mac addresses at the bottom of the page.

Make sure your total uplink and downlink bandwidth are accurate. You want them about 10% lower than the actual amount you receive under a speed test.

This method of bandwidth control permanently limits the device added. Its a much better choice to use the dynamic features outlined in the link i gave you.

A couple pointers from using dd-wrt since its inception on countless routers.

1. using virtual access points and repeaters on the same physical radio will significantly reduce the chip-sets lifetime.
2. don't jack up the TX power past what the factory firmware setting was. its usually about 27-30 Dbm, or the end result will be a significantly reduced router lifetime.
3. when you have the router in bridge or client bridge mode disable the spi firewall.

Comment: I have already set it up once using Mac and another using IP. It works completely fine on WAN port, in either configuration just not LAN & WLAN.

Comment: The image of the IP netmask settings is also wrong, you have no netmask set. It would be /24 for a private class c network

Comment: It does work through the lan and wlan. You can check qos at the command prompt, I suggest using the dynamic rules. They are a little more complicated to setup but it's well worth it.

Comment: I’ll replace the image. Another way of limiting it and checking whether QoS works is to set a bandwidth limit in uplink/downlink. I have a 10mbps and I specified 2000kbps there if you notice, but even them it hits 10 easily.

Comment: okay I’ll give it a shot like you said and post the update.

Comment: Don't forget, it's always a good idea to save > apply > reboot after changes to qos. Some models will not apply the new setting until it's soft rebooted

Comment: Let me know how it works out.

Comment: Updating the DD-WRT to the latest beta version and then following your tips made it work. Thank you so much.